# How to get Keyboard Height by the time app is opened

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard

I have used the below code for getting the keyboard height.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);

                int screenHeight = view.getRootView().getHeight();
                int keyboardHeight = screenHeight - rect.bottom;
                if(keyboardHeight != 0){
                    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                        AppConfig.landscapeKeyboardHeight = keyboardHeight;
                    else if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                        AppConfig.portraitKeyboardHeight = keyboardHeight;
                }
            }
        });
```

But this gives height only when the app opens keyboard for the first time at least. I want the height of keyboard even before the it gets open for the first time. Is there any way of doing this? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem before for getting the height of keyboard for showing some dialog boxes. You can use the method below to solve it.

```
rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);

            int screenHeight = rootView.getHeight();
            int keyboardHeight = screenHeight - (rect.bottom - rect.top);

            if(keyboardHeight > screenHeight / 3){
                keyboardActive = true;
                Log.d("Keyboard", "Active");

            }
            else{
                keyboardActive = false;
                Log.d("Keyboard", "Not Active");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried but it's still got keyboard height when keyboard show